# Help setting up sphinx

Tags: mysql, linux, sphinx

ok I downloaded sphinx-0.9.9.tar.gz to my desktop

I extracted to a folder called sphinx on my desktop.

I run:

> cd ~/Desktop/sphinx
>
> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/sphinx
>   --with-mysql

alot of stuff happens.

Then I run this line

> make

I get this error:

> make: *** No targets specified and no
>   makefile found.  Stop.

I am on ubuntu 10.04 I have already installed apache2, php5, mysql, mysqladmin

I have no clue what the error means.

### Update

actually I noticed after I run:

> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/sphinx
>   --with-mysql

I get this:

> ERROR: cannot find MySQL include
>   files.
>
> Check that you do have MySQL include
>   files installed. The package name is
>   typically 'mysql-devel'.
>
> If include files are installed on your
>   system, but you are still getting this
>   message, you should do one of the
>   following:
>
> 1) either specify includes location
>   explicitly, using
>   --with-mysql-includes; 2) or specify MySQL installation root location
>   explicitly, using --with-mysql; 3) or
>   make sure that the path to
>   'mysql_config' program is listed in
>   your PATH environment variable.
>
> To disable MySQL support, use
>   --without-mysql option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently I needed to first run:

> sudo aptitude install libmysql++-dev
>   libmysqlclient15-dev checkinstall

via the instructions on the bottom of [this page](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=1711)

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 16.04 it helped to run:

```
sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev
```